# Grep causes entire system to freeze while comparing two files

Tags: linux, memory, freeze, arch-linux, grep

What I wanted is to compare two files and check if every line in `file1` exists in `file2`. My first try: `grep -v -f file2 file1`. This resulted in a lot of syntax errors (**but didn't freeze anything**). I quickly found out it's because I need to use `-F` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38208473/9138821). So I ran `grep -Fvf file2 file2` and seconds later my entire system was frozen for minutes, until xorg crashed entirely.

I was able to take this picture of the frozen screen:
[image: resource manager]

And once I was finally able to enter tty2, I was greeted with this:
[image: errors]

**Questions:**

1. Was the cause of the frozen system simply that it ran out of RAM, or is there more?
2. Why does grep use ~14GB RAM (and wants more) for comparing two 250MB files?
3. I could use tools to limit the RAM grep can use, but AFAIK all of those will simply kill the process once it reached x GB of RAM, so this won't help me. What does one do in such situation? Let's assume we have to use grep.

**Edit:** I already found a workaround without grep. I'm really curious about why and how this can happen still though. +14GB RAM for two 250MB files just seems odd to me. I'm **not** looking for an alternative on how I can compare my files with this question.

Comment: Any reason you did not use the diff command?   That would seem a more appropriate tool for this job.

Comment: @davidgo I tried diff like this: `diff --new-line-format="" --unchanged-line-format=""  F1 F2` but it didn't work. I tried sorting the lines too. It printed thousands of lines that are in both files. Sorting probably made it worse as the files are already sorted (as in, the bottom of file1 should match the bottom of file2) and sorting it (alphabetically) would only make it worse. I got what I wanted by simply cutting off the first ~210k lines of file2 and then using `diff` again to make sure the contents are exactly identical. I'm still interested in answers about grep using that much RAM tho.

Comment: Why would you not have simply used  "diff file1 file2" ?  (--new-line-format and --unchanged-line-format do not even exist in my version of diff)

Comment: @davidgo Because that would show me all the differences, when I just want to know if every line in file1 also exists in file2. The +200k lines in file2 which aren't in file1 would flood the output. I edited my question to be more clear. I'm really more after an explanation for grep's behaviour than getting an alternative for the operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The reason was definitely it ran out of memory.
2. Because you are not "comparing two files", you are using one 250MB file as a source of **patterns** for grep. Grep compiles those patterns into a variant of a [deterministic finite automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton), and the representation of this DFAs takes up memory. If you have many patterns (like 250MB of patterns), it takes up a *lot* of space, because transforming the [nondeterministic finite automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton) that corresponds to many patterns into a DFA can cause exponential blowup.

`grep` is made to look very efficiently for a few patterns in one or several large files. It's not made to "compare" files. If you try to use it for that, things can go wrong. As they did in your case.

Complexity matters, that's why you learn about O-notation and all this fancy stuff.

3. In such a situation, you use a program that is made for your situation, not a program that uses an algorithm which is space-exponential for your kind of problem.

You said you didn't want to know the alternative, but since it involves a lesser known tool, I'll tell you anyway:

If the question is "does every line of file1 also exists in file2, regardless of order", what you do is to sort both files, and then you use `comm`, which expects sorted files, and puts out (1) lines in file1, but not in file2, (2) lines in file2, but not in file1 and (3) lines in both files, at your convenience.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for in an answer, thank you a lot for the great explanation.